# Problem with referencing the service in WCF (C#)

Tags: c#, wcf, service, reference

I need to reference a service that is a part of another project.
I have declared and implemented the contract of the service and then tried to
add a standard reference (right click ->Add Service reference, and added

`http://localhost:8000/MyService?wsdl`

The proxy has been generated and it should work at the first glance, however every time I try to run the program I got:

> Could not find default endpoint
>   element that references the contract
>   "MyService.IMyContract" in the
>   ServiceModel client configuration
>   section. This might be because no
>   configuration file was found for your
>   application, or because no endpoint
>   element matching this contract could
>   be found in the client element.

Do you have any ideas how to solve the issue?
Here is a part of my config file (ServerModel section):

```
<client>
  <endpoint 
      address="http://localhost:8000/MyService" 
      binding="wsHttpBinding"
      bindingConfiguration="" 
      contract="MyService.IMyContract" name="" />
</client>
```

Any ideas?

Thank you in advance for the replies!

cheers

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/352654/could-not-find-default-endpoint-element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error would indicate the config that's being used doesn't have the necessary info in it.

If you have a web site, you need to make sure to put those config entries into the `web.config` of the web application.

If you have a console, Winforms or WPF app, you need to put those config entries into the `app.config` of your main app.

Something that happens every now and then is programmers having a class library which encapsulates the WCF calls, but they forget to copy the config entries from the class library's `app.config` to the main app's `app.config` or `web.config`. By default, .NET will *not* read the class library's `app.config` at runtime, so having the settings there doesn't do you any good.

Comment: Face palm... I kept changing config for different VS solution :)