# Web Service Creating Instance Problem -> Could not find default endpoint element that references contract 'MyWebService.ClassName'

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, class

i want to use the below Web-Service :

> https://acquirer.sb24.com/ref-payment/ws/ReferencePayment?WSDL

and builded config file after adding ->

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="PaymentIFBinding" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00"
                    receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false"
                    bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                    maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
                    messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
                    useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                    <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                    <security mode="Transport">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
                            realm="" />
                        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
                    </security>
                </binding>
                <binding name="PaymentIFBinding1" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00"
                    receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false"
                    bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                    maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
                    messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
                    useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                    <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                    <security mode="None">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
                            realm="" />
                        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="https://acquirer.sb24.com:443/ref-payment/ws/ReferencePayment"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="PaymentIFBinding"
                contract="SB24Service.PaymentIF" name="PaymentIFPort" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

i want to call verifyTransaction method of this WebService :

```
PaymentIFClient pic = new PaymentIFClient();  

double pic_result = pic.verifyTransaction(str1, str2);
```

but the first line throws the below error :

> Could not find default endpoint element that references contract
>   'SB24Service.PaymentIF' in the ServiceModel client configuration
>   section. This might be because no configuration file was found for
>   your application, or because no endpoint element matching this
>   contract could be found in the client element.

**EDIT :**

> "This error can arise if you are calling the service in a class
>   library and calling the class library from another project." -> My
>   Situation is like this ...

what should i change i configuration file ?
thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Could not find default endpoint element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/352654/could-not-find-default-endpoint-element)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Editing wcf configuration by hand is tricky, as there are many sections that need to be correct and correctly reference each other. Try opening your app.config file in [SvcConfigEditor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732009.aspx) (also available from the Tools menu in Viusal Studio). It is way easier to get things correct when having GUI help on what to do.

Comment: thanks for comment and answer / so nice GUI ... / but which parts should i change ? why the default settings have problem ?