# How to call WCF service by WEB App -> Class Library -> WCF Service?

Tags: asp.net, wcf, .net-4.0, endpoint

I have a WCF Service Project.
I have another Class library project where I am calling the WCF service.
And from a Web Application i am callign the class librabry.

In the Class library I am writing

```
new ChannelFactory<CompanyServiceContract>("CompanyServiceEndPoint")
```

But an exception is coming which says unable to find the End point "CompanyServiceEndPoint".

I have seen this question [Could not find default endpoint element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/352654/could-not-find-default-endpoint-element) but I don't know about **WS configuration settings into the main projects app.config**

Can someone please help?

Comment: In a web application, the endpoint configuration needs to go into the web.config file.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't "CompanyServiceEndPoint" actually be an endpoint? (a string url to the service method, eg: "http://me.me.com/myService" or an EndpointAddress).

Can you access your wcf endpoint by other means? a browser? Fiddler ? WcfTestClient?

Did you define an endpoint for the scv in code? 
eg: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734681.aspx

I think in the first instance you need to find out if the fault is with the service or the client that calls the service. If you can hit the service with any of the clients above - then look to the client.