# Self hosting WCF contract not found

Tags: wcf, silverlight, sql-server-2008, hosting

I used this MSDN example to construct my console host app:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731758.aspx

It works I have a service running, while running I can add it as a Service Reference to my Silverlight class library ViewModel and I can see it running in a browser.

However when I run my Silverlight app I get the following error message:

> Could not find default endpoint element that references contract
>   'ServiceLayer.IServiceLayer' in the ServiceModel client configuration
>   section. This might be because no configuration file was found for
>   your application, or because no endpoint element matching this
>   contract could be found in the client element.

This is my service code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Activation;
using Model;

namespace ServiceLayer
{
    [ServiceContract(Namespace = "ServiceLayer")] //This has to match references or updating the service reference will not work.
    public interface IServiceLayer
    {
        [OperationContract] //This is needed for each method.
        string Compile(string cscode, string name, string type, int token);

        [OperationContract] //This is needed for each method.
        string LoginClick(string username, string password, bool createuser, int token);

        [OperationContract]
        bool IsLoggedIn(int token);

        [OperationContract] //This is needed for each method.
        object[] GetMessages(int token);

        [OperationContract] //This is needed for each method.
        int GetToken(int token);

        [OperationContract] //This is needed for each method.
        string[][] GetPlugins(int token);

        [OperationContract] //This is needed for each method.
        string Finalize(int token, string[] descriptions);

        [OperationContract] //This is needed for each method.
        object[][] Communicate(string methodName, int token, object[] args);
    }

    [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
    public class ServiceLayer : IServiceLayer
    {
        public string Compile(string cscode, string name, string type, int token)
        {
            // Add your operation implementation here
            ModelInterface MI = new ModelInterface();
            return MI.Compile(cscode, name, type, token);
        }

        public String LoginClick(string username, string password, bool createuser, int token)
        {
            ModelInterface MI = new ModelInterface();
            return MI.LoginClick(username, password, createuser, token);
        }

        public bool IsLoggedIn(int token)
        {
            ModelInterface MI = new ModelInterface();
            return MI.IsLoggedIn(token);
        }

        public object[] GetMessages(int token)
        {
            ModelInterface MI = new ModelInterface();
            return MI.GetMessages(token);
        }

        public int GetToken(int token)
        {
            ModelInterface MI = new ModelInterface();
            return MI.GetToken(token);
        }

        public string[][] GetPlugins(int token)
        {
            ModelInterface MI = new ModelInterface();
            return MI.GetPlugins(token);
        }

        public string Finalize(int token, string[] descriptions)
        {
            ModelInterface MI = new ModelInterface();
            return MI.Finalize(token, descriptions);
        }

        public object[][] Communicate(string methodName, int token, object[] args)
        {
            ModelInterface MI = new ModelInterface();
            return MI.Communicate(methodName, token, args);
        }
        // Add more operations here and mark them with [OperationContract]
    }
}
```

This is the ServiceReferences.ClientConfig of the ViewModel:

```
<configuration>
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IServiceLayer" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
                maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
                <security mode="None" />
            </binding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IServiceLayer1" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
                maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
                <security mode="None" />
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:3263/front" binding="basicHttpBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IServiceLayer" contract="IServiceLayer"
            name="BasicHttpBinding_IServiceLayer" />
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:3263/front" binding="basicHttpBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IServiceLayer1" contract="ServiceLayer.IServiceLayer"
            name="BasicHttpBinding_IServiceLayer1" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

And this is the Web.Config file of the project with the website hosting the Silverlight app.
I post it because I tried this [Could not find default endpoint element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/352654/could-not-find-default-endpoint-element)
guide - ie copying the servicemodel section from the VM config to the web.Config below also:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <customBinding>
        <binding name="OrgOS.Web.ServerCommunicationService.customBinding0">
          <binaryMessageEncoding/>
          <httpTransport/>
        </binding>
        <binding name="OrgOS.Web.ServiceLayer.customBinding0">
          <binaryMessageEncoding/>
          <httpTransport/>
        </binding>
      </customBinding>
    </bindings>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
    <services>
      <service name="OrgOS.Web.ServiceLayer">
        <endpoint address="" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="OrgOS.Web.ServiceLayer.customBinding0" contract="OrgOS.Web.ServiceLayer"/>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

My server I rented came without ASP.NET despite the fact I paid for it, support is on leave and I have deadlines coming up!
Trying to get WCF working is driving me mad - please help me...

Why is it so freaking hard to show a simple Silverlight project...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah nevermind; you have to post the config settings in both the View Silverlight project, the web project AND the ViewModel Silverlight project.

You must also delete all endpoints and bindings, but one to avoid getting things confused.

Also changed things to make sure namespace="namespace" fits the actual namespace.

... not that things work for that reason, oh noes all I get is invalid results.

FML right now.