# WCF Service communicate with methods and DLL pointing to Class

Tags: wcf, visual-studio-2008

As my title may be confusing, I am a little myself. If I have a WCF service running which calls methods from class `MyDataAccessLayer` and I also have a DLL which I use as a reference in my project that calls methods from `MyDataAccessLayer`, can this be the cause to this issue:

Could not find default endpoint element that references contract '`WCFTestService.ITestService`' in the `ServiceModel` client configuration section. This might be because no configuration file was found for your application, or because no endpoint element matching this contract could be found in the client element.

I am trying to understand WCF as much as possible, and I have checked the app.config file a thousand times and I have not seen any issues with my endpoint settings. Any thoughts?

Comment: Remember that the configuration used is the one in the assembly you are running from, not what you are referencing.  Is your configuration in the application you have as your Startup Application in Visual Studio?

Comment: Have you had an opportunity to look through this thread?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/352654/could-not-find-default-endpoint-element

Comment: yes it is in the application that is the startup

Comment: I had landed on that thread, which is why I was wondering if referencing the DLL which contains the MyDataAccessLayer class and using the service to call methods from that class as well.