# Could not find endpoint element when consume WCF service

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, wcf-binding

Getting the below error when trying to consume `WCF service`. `I looked into this issue and both name and contract values are same in both config files`.

> Could not find endpoint element with name 'BasicHttpBinding_IService1'
>   and contract 'ServiceReference1.IService1' in the ServiceModel client
>   configuration section. This might be because no configuration file was
>   found for your application, or because no endpoint element matching
>   this name could be found in the client element.

WCF service is class liberary in my solution and i am trying consume it in another class liberary project under same solution.

Client.config

```
  <endpoint address="http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/WcfServiceLibrary1/Service1/"
    binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService1"
    contract="ServiceReference1.IService1" name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" />
</client>
```

WCF config file

```
<configuration>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />
  </system.web>
  <!-- When deploying the service library project, the content of the config file must be added to the host's 
  app.config file. System.Configuration does not support config files for libraries. -->
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="WcfServiceLibrary1.Service1">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress = "http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/WcfServiceLibrary1/Service1/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <!-- Service Endpoints -->
        <!-- Unless fully qualified, address is relative to base address supplied above -->
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="WcfServiceLibrary1.IService1">
          <!-- 
              Upon deployment, the following identity element should be removed or replaced to reflect the 
              identity under which the deployed service runs.  If removed, WCF will infer an appropriate identity 
              automatically.
          -->
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost"/>
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <!-- Metadata Endpoints -->
        <!-- The Metadata Exchange endpoint is used by the service to describe itself to clients. --> 
        <!-- This endpoint does not use a secure binding and should be secured or removed before deployment -->
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, 
          set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" httpsGetEnabled="True"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, 
          set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment 
          to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>

</configuration>
```

Comment: can you see that the service is available in the browser?

Comment: It is available in the browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem as you said in your question" `You are trying to consume the service in a class library and calling the class library from another project."` Refer to this link for original answer. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/352654/could-not-find-default-endpoint-element)

To solve your issue you just need to copy client binding details to main caller project configuation file.

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" />
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/WcfServiceLibrary1/Service1/"
        binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService1"
        contract="ServiceReference1.IService1" name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: Let me see if this can fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try fullname identifiers with complete namespaces for your service name and contract.

```
<service name="SOLUTIONNAME.WcfServiceLibrary1.Service1">
     <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" 
     contract="SOLUTIONNAME.WcfServiceLibrary1.IService1">
     ...

 </service>
```