# error on wcf application when used as resource to move received data to asp.net web API

Tags: c#, rest, wcf, asp.net-web-api, console-application

so bascially i have a console application acting as a client software receiving data from a WCF feed. this works just fine when i want to do a console.writeline and print the data i'm getting in the console. I don't control the service end of the WCF feed so i have to use this console client software to access the data.

I'm trying to build an ASP.net web api application to pass this data to my own client via REST api. There are other complex reasons i have to do it this way but when it comes down to it i have to. I've built the basic web api for doing a GET to get the information. added the console application as a resource to the web api application but get an error message when I make the GET call.

This is the URL i'm using to make the GET call.

```
http://localhost:60421/api/CallData?skillNumber=92
```

After i make this call i get the below error message

[ERROR] System.InvalidOperationException occurred
      HResult=0x80131509
      Message=Could not find default endpoint element that references contract 'FeedService.IFeedService' in the ServiceModel client configuration section. This might be because no configuration file was found for your application, or because no endpoint element matching this contract could be found in the client element.
      Source=
      StackTrace:

The error occurs in this cs file. I've commented at the line it occurs in.

```
using ScoreBoardClientTest.FeedService;

namespace ScoreBoardClientTest
{
    public class FeedServiceAgent : IFeedServiceAgent, IFeedServiceCallback
    {
        private static FeedServiceClient _feedServiceClient;
        private ConnectionStats.ConnectionStatus _connectionStatus;

        private bool _retrying;
        private bool _disposed;

        public FeedServiceAgent()       //(IEventAggregator eventAggregator)
        {
            //Guard.ArgumentNotNull(eventAggregator, "eventAggregator");

            //_eventAggregator = eventAggregator;

            InitializeServiceClient();
        }

        public event MessageReceivedEventHandler MessageReceived;


                public void InitializeServiceClient()
        {


// The error message occurs at the line right below this
                _feedServiceClient = new FeedServiceClient(new InstanceContext(this));
                _feedServiceClient.InnerChannel.Opening += OnOpening;
                _feedServiceClient.InnerChannel.Opened += OnOpened;
                _feedServiceClient.InnerChannel.Closing += OnClosing;
                _feedServiceClient.InnerChannel.Closed += OnClosed;
                _feedServiceClient.InnerChannel.Faulted += OnFaulted;
            }

            private void DisposeServiceClient()
            {
                if (_feedServiceClient == null)
                    return;

                try
                {
                _feedServiceClient.InnerChannel.Opening -= OnOpening;
                _feedServiceClient.InnerChannel.Opened -= OnOpened;
                _feedServiceClient.InnerChannel.Closing -= OnClosing;
                _feedServiceClient.InnerChannel.Closed -= OnClosed;
                _feedServiceClient.InnerChannel.Faulted -= OnFaulted;
                _feedServiceClient.Abort();
            }
            catch
            {
                //Don't care.
            }
            finally
            {
                _feedServiceClient = null;
            }
        }

        public ConnectionStats.ConnectionStatus ConnectionStatus
        {
            get { return _connectionStatus; }
            set
            {
                _connectionStatus = value;
                PublishConnectionStatus();
            }
        }

        private void PublishConnectionStatus()
        {

        }
        private void ProcessCmsData(A cmsData)
        {
            if (cmsData == null)
                return;

            var skill = new Skill();
            var agents = new List<Agent>();
            var cmLookupdata = new List<CmLookupData>();
            //  LookupData lookupdata = new LookupData(); 
            if (cmsData.C != null && cmsData.C.Length > 0)
                LookupDataTranslator.Translate(cmsData.C, cmLookupdata);

            if (cmsData.AMember != null)
                SkillTranslator.Translate(cmsData.AMember, skill, cmLookupdata);

            if (cmsData.B != null && cmsData.B.Length > 0)
                AgentTranslator.Translate(cmsData.B, agents, cmsData.AMember.A, cmsData.AMember.CmId); // passing skill params to validate the cmid to discard bad data 


            var mappedCmsData = new CmsData(skill, agents, cmLookupdata);

            if (MessageReceived != null)
                MessageReceived(this, new MessageReceivedEventArgs(mappedCmsData, null));
        }

        #region FeedServiceClient Channel Events

        private void OnOpening(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            _connectionStatus = ConnectionStats.ConnectionStatus.Connecting;
        }

        private void OnOpened(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            _connectionStatus = ConnectionStats.ConnectionStatus.Connected;
        }

        private void OnClosing(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            _connectionStatus = ConnectionStats.ConnectionStatus.Disconnecting;
        }

        private void OnClosed(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            _connectionStatus = ConnectionStats.ConnectionStatus.Disconnected;
        }

        private void OnFaulted(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            _connectionStatus = ConnectionStats.ConnectionStatus.Disconnected;

            if (!_retrying)
                ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate
                {
                    Reconnect();
                });
        }

        #endregion


        private void Reconnect()
        {
            _retrying = true;

            _connectionStatus = ConnectionStats.ConnectionStatus.Reconnecting;

            // We don't want each client attempting the first reconnect all at the same time.
            var random = new Random();
            int randomWaitValue = random.Next(1, 10000);

            Thread.Sleep(randomWaitValue);

            // Try reconnecting 10 times.
            for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
            {
                try
                {
                    DisposeServiceClient();

                    _feedServiceClient = new FeedServiceClient(new InstanceContext(this));
                    _feedServiceClient.Open();
                    _feedServiceClient.InnerChannel.Opening += OnOpening;
                    _feedServiceClient.InnerChannel.Opened += OnOpened;
                    _feedServiceClient.InnerChannel.Closing += OnClosing;
                    _feedServiceClient.InnerChannel.Closed += OnClosed;
                    _feedServiceClient.InnerChannel.Faulted += OnFaulted;

                    _connectionStatus = ConnectionStats.ConnectionStatus.Reconnected;

                    _retrying = false;

                    //_logger.Info(String.Format("The Scoreboard Client was able to reconnect after {0} retries.", i)) ;  

                    return;
                }
                catch (Exception exception)
                {
                    //_logger.Error(String.Format("The Scoreboard Client is unable to reconnect: {0}", exception)) ;  

                    // Wait 30 seconds between retries to reduce network congestion.
                    Thread.Sleep(30000);
                }
            }

            //_logger.Info("The Scoreboard Client was unable to reconnect after 10 retries.") ;  

            _connectionStatus = ConnectionStats.ConnectionStatus.UnableToConnect;
        }

        #region Implementation of IDisposable

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }

        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (!_disposed)
                if (disposing)
                {
                    // Dispose managed resources here.
                    DisposeServiceClient();
                }

            _disposed = true;
        }

        #endregion

        public void NotifyCmsData(A cmsData)
        {
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate
            {
                ProcessCmsData(cmsData);
            });
        }

        public void Subscribe(string eventTopic, int cmId)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(eventTopic))
                return;

            InvokeAction(x => x.Subscribe(eventTopic, cmId));
        }

        public void Unsubscribe(string eventTopic, int cmId)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(eventTopic))
                return;

            InvokeAction(x => x.Unsubscribe(eventTopic, cmId));
        }

        public void RefreshCmsData()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public LookupData GetLookupData()
        {
            LookupData lookupdata = new LookupData();
            try
            {
                LookupDataTranslator.Translate(_feedServiceClient.GetLookupData(), lookupdata);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                //if (_logger != null)
                //    _logger.Error("Exception in finding the lookup data. Exception:" + e.Message);
                throw e;
            }
            return lookupdata; 
        }

        private void InvokeAction(Action<IFeedService> action)
        {
            try
            {
                action(_feedServiceClient);
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                //_logger.Error(" Exception in FeedService InvokeAction:" + exception.ToString());

                _connectionStatus = ConnectionStats.ConnectionStatus.UnableToConnect;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The console application has a properly configured config file for the console application which is what the error message suggests does not exist. also, as i said above the console application functions fully by itself.

QUESTION
How do you use a WCF console application as a resource for a web api successfully?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/352654/could-not-find-default-endpoint-element
This was able to successfully answer my question. i'll mark it completed at a later point

Answer (score 0):

I had to include the FeedService web URL inside of the web api service as long as the console application